# How does this function assignment work?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I was studying some C code from a college book I have (the subject of the book is Linux programming), and I came across some lines of code I don't understand. I have done some research but I haven't find anything on Internet. Can someone explain this code to me?

I know what environment variables are, the part I don't understand is how this `int (*det)(), det()` function works. Sorry if my title is not correct, I just didn't know how to describe the subject better.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int (*det)();
    det = getenv("foo");      
    det();
    return 0;
}
```

*** Thank you for your replies.is there any way to make this program functional, for example print "hallo"?

Comment: Best troll I've read here, this week.

Comment: `stidio.h`, seriously?

Comment: The keyword to search for is "Function Pointers"

Comment: `int (*det)()` is a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns a int. It is then assigned the result of `getenv("foo")`, presumably a memory address where such a function resides and then called with `det();`. Note that getting and calling a memory address from a enviroment string is unsafe and will probably fail if the memory does not belong to you (if it did, why get it trough such dubious means?).

Comment: @user1320881 Actually it's a (pointer to a) function that accepts any number of parameters.

Comment: @Daniel Jour: True, thanks, was thinking of C++.

Comment: @user1320881 That's a reasonable answer, but comments are not for that.

Comment: @RaymondChen: good find, but I think the point is here that it declares a regular local variable, right?

Comment: @RadLexus And indeed that's what the answers to the possible duplicate say: It's a variable declaration. (SO search ignores punctuation, which makes searching for dups of questions about operators and punctuation really hard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As somebody already pointed out

```
det = getenv("foo");
```

doesn't make much sense and i hope your compiler is smart enough so
that you don't get away with it.Below might be what you were expecting to see in that book :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char* getenv(const char*);
/* The above statement is not mandatory but would make the code more 
 * readable. The keyword "extern" here implies that the function is 
 * is defined elsewhere.
 */

int main(void)
{
    char* (*det)(const char*) = getenv;
    printf("PATH env variable contains : %s\n", (*det)("PATH"));
    /* Replace path with your own environment variable */
    printf("Press any key to continue..\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am just printing some stuff here, change the usage to satisfy your needs.

**References**

[getenv()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_getenv.htm) prototype here.

Answer (score 5):

In general, it does not work.  You are trying to assign a `char*` (string) to a function pointer.  A reasonable compiler will reject this.

However, not all compilers are reasonable.  If you do manage to compile and execute this code, you have created a program vulnerable to attack via the environment variable `foo`.  This is because if you do manage to execute the contents of `foo`, and they are indeed executable on your machine, you will have shifted control of the process out of your C program and into whatever code exists in `foo`.  This is nonportable, probably nonworking, definitely unsafe, and should never be attempted.

Also, the book you got this from is, at a guess, something about information security.  If not, burn it.